# Why such a big difference between results of Integrate and NIntegrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic

Studying [an interesting article of Daniel Lichtblau](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5832), I consider a variation of an example from it, calculating an improper integral

```
Integrate[RealAbs[Sin[x - y]]^(-2/3), {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]
```

> `-((12 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[-(1/3)] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/6, 1/2, 2/3}, {7/6, 7/6}, 1])/ Gamma[1/6])`

This is not very useful analytic expression, so

```
N[%]
```

> `16.7126`

Then I compare that result with the numeric one

```
NIntegrate[RealAbs[Sin[x - y]]^(-2/3), {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
Exclusions -> {y == x}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
```

> `22.8915`

The latest result is produced without any warning. How to explain so big difference between the numbers? Could this difference be decreased? Which result is more reliable?

Comment: It should be fairly simple to reduce this to a 1D integral (`x-y -> z`).  That ought to make it more obvious which is the correct answer.

Comment: @mikado: Thank you. However, this reduction is not so simple.

Comment: Note that you have exactly one period of the function over the integration interval.  This makes the change of variable much simpler.  In fact, you can just replace `x-y` with `x`

Comment: @mikado: Can you kindly ground your claim? How about the difference between the exact and numeric double integrals?

Comment: @mikado: Did you pay your attention that the set $x-y=0$ is smaller than the set $x-y=\pm \frac 1 2$ in rhe square $[0,2\pi]^2$?

Comment: @mikado: The smallest period of $|\sin x|$ equals $\pi$, not $2\pi$. I am right, aren't I?

Comment: Period of `Abs[Sin[x]]` is `Pi`.  Using Maxima, with the variable substitution, I get the result `Pi beta(1/6,1/2)`.  This agrees with your numeric result.

Comment: @mikado: That's great, but I am waiting your answer to my question and comments.

Comment: @mikado: Making use of your suggestion, `Integrate[RealAbs[Sin[z]]^(-2/3), {z, 0, Pi}]` performs $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}\approx7.28595$ and `Integrate[RealAbs[Sin[z]]^(-2/3), {z, 0, 2*Pi}]` produces the twice bigger result. Your words "This agrees with your numeric result" do not correspond to reality.

Comment: I think that you have doubled the integration interval

Comment: @mikado: Sorry, don't understand you.  I repeat "I am waiting your answer to my question and comments".

Comment: @Teabelly: See [so big difference](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=so+big+difference&source=hp&ei=9UCAYJSGK4KckwXyzKjYCQ&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYIBPBa5GJh-XvKF2lOzKUukcUdc7KNab&oq=so+big+difference&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjoCCAA6AgguOgQIABAeOgYIABAKEB46BggAEAUQHjoICAAQBRAKEB46CAgAEBYQChAeOgUIIRCgAToECCEQFToICCEQFhAdEB46BwghEAoQoAE6CAgAEMcBEKMCOgUILhCTAjoKCAAQDRAFEAoQHjoICAAQDRAFEB46CAgAEAgQDRAeUM4PWKWjAWDUsgFoEHAAeAGAAYcFiAGDSZIBDTEuMTUuMTAuMS4zLjWYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEA&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjU1NT5z4_wAhUCzqQKHXImCpsQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer to my question. First, it is enough to consider
the integration over the triangle with vertices at $(0,0),\,(0,\pi),\,(\pi,\pi)$.
Second, we make the change of the variables $s=y-x,\,t=x+y$, using the idea of @mikado. The inverse map is
$x =\frac {t-s} 2,\, y=\frac {t+s} 2$ and its Jacobian determinant equals $-\frac 1 2$. Now the set of the integration is
the triangle with its vertices at $(0,0),\,(0,2\pi),\,(\pi,\pi)$ and the double integral under consideration
becomes $$\int\limits_0^\pi \int\limits_s^{2\pi-s} \frac 1 {\sin(s)^{2/3}}\left|- \frac 1 2 \right| \,dtds=
\int\limits_0^\pi \frac {\pi-s} {\sin(s)^{2/3}}\,ds.$$

Mathematica calculates the latter integral by

```
Integrate[(Pi - s)/Sin[s]^(2/3), {s, 0, Pi}]
```

> `(3 \[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[7/6])/Gamma[2/3]`

```
N[(3 \[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[7/6])/Gamma[2/3]]
```

> `11.4447`

This coinsides with the result by @AlexTrounev. Let us consider how Mathematica 12.2 does the job.
Its result for the antiderivative

```
Integrate[(Pi - s)/Sin[s]^(2/3), s, Assumptions -> s > 0 && s <= Pi]
```

> `1/2 Sin[s]^( 1/3) (-6 s Cos[s] Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 1, 7/6,  Sin[s]^2] + (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/3] HypergeometricPFQ[{2/3, 2/3, 1}, {7/6, 5/3},  Sin[s]^2] Sin[s])/(2^(1/3) Gamma[7/6] Gamma[5/3]) - (2 \[Pi] Cos[s] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 5/6, 3/2, Cos[s]^2])/(Sin[s]^2)^(1/6))`

is not correct in view of

```
Plot[%,{s,0,Pi}]
```

[image]
which shows a discontinuous function.

I think Mathematica knows the integral
`Integrate[(Pi - s)/Sin[s]^(2/3), {s, 0, Pi}]` as a table value, though I don't find it
in a handbook of Gradshtein&Ruezhik. Numeric calculations confirm it by

```
Table[NIntegrate[(Pi - s)/Sin[s]^(2/3), {s, 10^(-k), Pi}], {k, 1, 4}]
```

> `{7.10428, 9.41585, 10.5023, 11.0073}`

Comment: Do you really think that Mathematica knows? There are rules for interpretation every combination of parameters. The question is why these  interpretations are differ for `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` in versions 12.0-12.2 while in v.11.1 they are the same? My opinion that it is connected with interpretation of `RealAbs`.  It is why I remove this function in my answer. The second problem is interpretation of power `2/3`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: Your guess that `RealAbs` causes an incorrect answer is built on the sand. The command `Integrate[RealAbs[Sin[x - y]]^(-1/2), {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]` produces the correct answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: I'd like to add that `Integrate[(Pi - s)/RealAbs[Sin[s]]^(2/3), {s, 0, Pi}]` also produces `(3 \[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[7/6])/Gamma[2/3]`.

Comment: Even your analysis is good (+1), the main problem is not explained. Why `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` give different answer?

Comment: @AlexTrounev: After the change of variables or/and  your (and MichaelE2's) representation of the integrand the results are concordant. I don't know " How to explain so big difference between the numbers?" so I asked it.

Comment: I find it good that Mathematica numerically cracks some double improper integrals.

Answer (score 3):

For a real function we can transform `RealAbs[Sin[x - y]]^(-2/3)` to `1/(1 - Cos[x - y]^2)^(1/3)`, then we have

```
Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x - y]^2)^(1/3), {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]

Out[]= (\[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[1/6])/Gamma[2/3]
```

Numerical result is `22.88949310061915`. It can be compare to

```
NIntegrate[1/(1 - Cos[x - y]^2)^(1/3), {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
  Exclusions -> {x == y}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

Out[]= 22.889493100619489917
```

Comment: MA11.1 gives your analytical result $\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$ directly, without any reformulations.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: All that is not so simple. Let us consider the inner integral `Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x - y]^2)^(1/3), {y, 0, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> x >= 0 && x <= Pi]` which results in `ConditionalExpression[(6 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[7/6])/Gamma[2/3], 
 2 x < \[Pi]]`. Pay your attention to `2 x < \[Pi]]`. I am using 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The command `Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x - y]^2)^(1/3), {y, 0, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> x >= Pi/2 && x <= Pi]` results in `(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/6])/Gamma[2/3]`, Combining these, we obtain the right (I hope) answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: Don't make me laudh. It's still unclear to me whether `Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x - y]^2)^(1/3), {y, 0, Pi},   Assumptions -> x >= Pi/2 && x <= Pi]` formally applies the Newton-Leibniz formula. not paying attention to the singularity at `y=x` or the command does consider it as an improper integral. `NIntegrate` also may switch to the symbolic integration. BTW, `Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x - y]^2)^(1/3), y, 
 Assumptions -> x >= Pi/2 && x <= Pi` results in `-((3 Sqrt[Cos[x - y]^2]
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/6, 1/2, 7/6, Sin[x - y]^2] Tan[x - y])/(Sin[
   x - y]^2)^(1/3)) `.  Regard.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: The question is still open. Do you understand me? Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need. Regard again.

Comment: @user64494 This question not about integration  but only about `ReAbs[]` function interpretation in the old versions like 11.1 and in the new one  like 12.2. May be the new result of `Integrate` comes from some updates. Actually this function has been introduced in v.11.1 and not been changed in v. 12.2. Nevertheless I have tested  your example   in v. 12.0 and got same result 16.7095. So we can ask Mathematica stuff why they take different brunches in v.11.1 and vv12.0-12.2. Or maybe this is bug.

Comment: @yarchik So it looks like the interpretation of `RealAbs[]` is different in v.11.1 and in vv12.0-12.2. May be it is a bug.

Comment: As it is shown in my answer, Mathematica finds that integral as a table value, not as an interated integral.

Answer (score 1):

I'm left unsure what is the correct answer from the above analyses.  Personally, I believe the integral should be evaluated as an improper or  principal-valued integral.  In this case, the singularity is the line y=x.  Below I create a principal-valued integral function f1[x], then integrate this function over the requisite domain:

```
f1[x_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[RealAbs[Sin[x - y]]^(-2/3), {y, 0, x, 
 Pi},Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
NIntegrate[f1[x], {x, 0, Pi}]

Out[8]= 22.8895
```

It's just more simple-understanding this way and one more intuitively reasonable I think.  Also I have doubt change of variable is applicable in a domain with singularities.

Comment: Why `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`  compute different output?

Comment: I reviewed briefly Daniel's article.  There can be problems with Integrate handling singularities.  I suspect it is not handling them correctly in this case.  There is also the problem of interpreting associated multi-valued functions involved.  That jump in the plot above is a clear example of a branch-discontinuity which would lead to an incorrect answer if an analytically-continuous result is desired.

Comment: It is very good. But why in your answer there is no example with `Integrate`?

Comment: Good point Alex.  However, Integrate returns an analytic expression containing the underlying HypergeometricPFQ function which is multivalued.  In order to use this function correctly, an analytically-continuous route over the branching  would be needed similar to evaluating $$\oint 1/z dz$$ in terms of the logarithmic antiderivative.  Not sure how to do this for Hypergeometric and also I think Daniel and many others here more qualified to analyze this than me.

Comment: The double improper integral under consideration converges, so `Method->"PricipalValue"` does nothing. The same result is produced by `f1[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[RealAbs[Sin[x - y]]^(-2/3), {y, 0, Pi}]
NIntegrate[f1[x], {x, 0, Pi}]`. You simply numerically calculate the improper integral in a complicated way, no more and no less. This is not it.

Comment: The code `f1[x_] := 
 Integrate[RealAbs[Sin[x - y]]^(-2/3), {y, 0, x, Pi}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True]
Integrate[Evaluate[f1[x]], {x, 0, Pi}]` fails.

Comment: @user64494:  Ok I made a mistake.  I accept that.   Down-voting my answer would have been more appropriate and professional than making a snobbish remark about my attempts.

Comment: @user64494 I removed the last sentence of your comment, it was not necessary in this otherwise valuable comment. Dominic, rough indeed but more educational than a silent down-vote.

Comment: @Kuba no such thing.  Rather it was a mockery of educational: people who malevolently try to discourage others from trying to solve a problem should be eliminated from the educational process.  If that gold star you guys gave me implies I am always suppose to know how to solve problems and get ridiculed if I don't then by all means remove it.  I didn't ask for it.

Comment: @Dominic Is user64494's comment, in its current form, a mockery? An honest question, I didn't focus on math so maybe I missed something. Your points are also valid otoh SE is not a discussion panel, it tries to keep clean question+answer format. Not saying anything about validity of your answer, as I said before I didn't focus on math here at all.

Comment: @Kuba. Please, it was all inappropriate in my view of how math and science in general should be conducted but further discussion distracts from the math and further poisons this thread in my opinion.    I have however always felt uncomfortable with the gold ranking on my name and request it be removed.  But unfortunately I can't contact you privately about this so must do so here in public.

Comment: `Method -> "PrincipalValue"` invokes a different internal code for handling the singularity, and, since the PV equals the standard value, it provides a valuable verification of the original numerical result. I'm not sure that the buggy behavior of the hidden, internal operations of `Integrate` in this case deserves much attention.

Comment: @Dominik: I mistakenly accepted your answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Please pay your attention to an incorrect antiderivative `Integrate[(Pi - s)/Sin[s]^(2/3), s, Assumptions -> s > 0 && s <= Pi]` too.